# How do I run SELECT queries on Oracle in QTP?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a dilemma, where a query that works fine in **Benthic Golden32** (or other database connection software) does not return any values in **QTP**.  As an example of the code I'm running:

```
set conn=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.ConnectionString ="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=SERVER;uid=USER;pwd=123456;" 
Set objRecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.open
SQL= "SELECT * FROM table"
objRecSet.Open SQL, conn

msgbox(objRecSet.RecordCount)
```

This returns -1.  Why? I am using the same user account in both Benthic and QTP and running the same query in both cases.  INSERT queries in QTP on the same account and table work fine.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the provider/driver, the CursorType, and the phase of the moon, .RecordCount can't give you the number of records before you looped over the resultset. Start your research [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194973/en-us); check the additional parameters to both .Open methods in the ADO Docs; consider to switch to a "SELECT COUNT" type of query to see how many rows you got.

Comment: Helpful, but annoying that .RecordCount doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlStatement = "select count(*) from emp"
Rec.Open sqlStatement,conn
Value = Rec.fields.item(0)
     msgbox Value
```

This directly prints the count of records from ur table. hope this helps.